# Load local assets from remote HTML - android app

Tags: android, html, local, assets

I'm trying to load local source such image via remote HTML on server.
I get this error when run the app :

Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/www/img/logo.png:0

how to solve this? anyone? :(

Comment: please show us the code of the specific line where you try to load that file.

Comment: on eclipse i'm wrote this to load HTML from server :

super.loadUrl("http://sampleURL/sample.html");

on HTML I'm wrote this to call local source file from android app :

<img src="file:///android_asset/www/img/logo.png"/>

And I get this error :

Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/www/img/logo.png:0

Comment: public class bn extends DroidGap
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("http://sampleURL/sample.html");
        
    }
    
}

Comment: do you use a webview?

Comment: load HTML from web view is no problem.. seem like permission issue..

Comment: i'm using phoneGap... dont know why it cant load local sources...

Comment: do you have any idea?

Comment: @Safrul Please don't use comments to expand on your question, edit your question instead. This way others might see the additional information more easily.

Comment: Sorry @Simon.. my mistakes...

Answer (score 0):

if the png is already in your assets folder just use this in your html:

```
<img src="www/img/logo.png"/>
```